# Adding CancellationToken to WebApi causes 415

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a .Net Core 2.1 WebAPI application with a method that takes no parameters.  When I add a single parameter to it (`CancellationToken cancellationToken`), all requests to it return `415 Unsupported media type`.  This is the same result that I get if I put in a user-defined class as a parameter, so I believe that perhaps the model binding for the `CancellationToken` isn't working right, because it should be binding it to the http cancellation token source (although I'm aware there are issues with it in 2.1).

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("MyRoute")]
    public async Task<IList<MyObject>> MyRouteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
        .AddCookie();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("DmpLicenseUpdaters", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new DmpLicenseUpdatersRequirement()));
        });

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddResponseCompression();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(ApplicationVersionHeaderFilter));
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(ExecutionPerformanceCustomHeaderFilter));
        })
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Configure:

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: I tried setting up a project using v2.1, with most of your sample code (other than the authorization and your custom filters), and it works fine. I suspect there is something else going wrong in code you haven't supplied.

Comment: @cbp Yeah, it's an existing app that we're trying to put this in and it's not working.  The problem is, I don't know what might be causing the problems.  I don't think there's anything else related to bindings in the code anywhere.  I tried checking the model binding, but couldn't find them once the app had started.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this HTTP 415 status code error by explicitly setting the [AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.allowvalidatingtoplevelnodes) to `true` when configuring the MVC service:

```
services.AddMvcCore(options => options.AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes = true)
```

Alternatively, you can also [set the compatibility version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/compatibility-version?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to 2.1 or later but this will also opt-in to other behaviours:

```
services.AddMvcCore().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
```

Or upgrade to ASP.NET Core 3 or later where I think the `CancellationToken` works out of the box without having to configure anything special.